# sql server configuration problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

i installed sql server in my home pc for personal use. When i planned to configure sql server through Surface Area configuration, i got one error like this : **"Could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.customcontrols, version= 9.0.242..0, culture = neutral, Publickeytocken = 89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependancies. The System cannot find the file specified. (SQSAC)"** . What i do for resolving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this link [Potential Solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/vststest/thread/78bc36da-20c4-4427-9be7-3acc120f462c) try...

```
sqlcmd -s <dbname>
use loadtest
exec sp_grantdbaccess 'domain\user','user'
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader','user'
```

1) Replace  with your database name.  If it is the default database, then this is .\sqlexpress

2) replace 'domain\user' with the account you want to give access to and replace 'user' with a username to store this in the database.  For example,

exec sp_grantdbaccess 'company\sean','sean'

3) Replace 'user' in the last statement with the user name you gave in the third statement.  So in my example,

exec sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader','sean'